# Demonstrate the statement in section 3.I.3 on the decomposition of the Möbius transformations!!!

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

[press here to view textbook question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZJam.png)

I'm wondering how to do this question. I believe the question wants to decompose the following statements together from the text book to find the Mobius function

Thank you in advance (:

Comment: Provide context. What is $M(z)$? Something like $az + b/cz +d$?

Comment: Have you had linear algebra?

Answer (score 1):

They basically gave you the solution. Let $f, g, h, i$ are the functions in that order.

Then notice what $i(h(g(f(z))))$ is:

$i(h(g(f(z)))) = i(h(g(z+d/c))) = i(h(\frac{1}{z + \frac{d}{c}})) = i(h(\frac{c}{cz+d})) = i(-\frac{ad-bc}{c^2}\frac{c}{cz+d}) = i(-\frac{ad - bc}{c(cz+d)}) = \frac{a}{c} - \frac{ad-bc}{c(cz+d)} = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$.

So $M = ihgf(z)$ as desired.